# Sql syntax newbie

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help I need to create a dashboard in Sql Server Reporting Services (Sql Server 2008 R2).  Idea is to highlight green if a building room has been deep cleaned last 30 days or red if over 30 days.   We don't have a tracking mechanism and we are cleaning same room multiple times within 30 days and we don't want that.   Not sure how to write Sql statement?

```
Table2
Bldg varchar(40),
BldgRoom varchar(40),
CleanDateTime DateTime ,
```

this is the closest i have gotten after hours of research.

```
select distinct Bldg, BldgRoom,  cleandatetime
FROM  Table2
where Table2.Bldg = @Bldg
```

Which returns multiple reds and greens of each room. I want to show the distinct rooms ex. 516 red or green, 517 red or green, 518 red or green, etc. but i keep getting duplicate red/green every room.

Comment: In the results, cleandatetime is a different value for all the rows?

Comment: Where is red/green coming from?

Comment: Need to clarify...an entry in table2 means the room was cleaned at cleandatetime?   So would you be interested in the most recent cleandatetime?  so select bldg,bldgroom, max(cleandatetime) from table2 where yaddayadda group by bldg,bldgroom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to is select the building and room with the most *recent* clean day, not all of the results.

```
SELECT Bldg, BldgRoom, MAX(CleanDateTime)
FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.Bldg = @Bldg
GROUP BY Bldg, BldgRoom
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to group by`Bldg` and compare the `MAX(CleanDateTime)` in each group:

```
SELECT 
    Bldg, 
    BldgRoom, 
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, MAX(CleanDateTime), GETDATE()) > 30 
         THEN 'Red'
         ELSE 'Green' 
    END AS CleanStatus
FROM Table2
WHERE Bldg = @Bldg
GROUP BY Bldg, BldgRoom
```

You *could* also just get the `MAX(CleanDateTime)` and do the date comparison in the report.